# Требования к хостингу для использования ClickOnce

Tags: c#, хостинг

Закончил программу, не опен-сорс, планирую распространять по методу ClickOnce.

Но нигде в сети не нахожу рекомендаций, где лучше разместить программу. Можно конечно обычный веб-хостинг взять, но не хочется экспериментировать впустую.

Достаточно ли будет обычного веб-хостинга?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про маркет (типа гуглоплея), через который программы распространять?

Comment: ClickOnce - это технология Мicrosoft, теоретически с любым хостингом работает - если не врут описания.

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает обычный хостинг? Абсолютно любой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будет достаточно обычного веб-хостинга. Публикуете ваше приложение в нужную папку хостинга, хоть через msbuild, хоть через visual studio, пишите красивую страничку для установки со ссылкой на Setup.exe и будет счастье.